# Speech Recognition callback registration fails

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I've been trying to register a callback URL for use with the speech recognition service but am not succeeding. 
I sent the following POST request with body `{}` and authentication.

```
https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/register_callback?callback_url=https://skaxsqsiq4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/watson/callback
```

I received this response:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "code_description": "Bad Request",
  "error": "unable to verify callback url, challenge_string is missing or incorrect"
}
```

Though calling my endpoint myself echos the challenge string

```
curl -XGET https://skaxsqsiq4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/watson/callback?challenge_string=12345
```

Returns:

```
12345
```

Answer (score 1):

[Watson Speech-to-Text register_callback returns only 400s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170060/watson-speech-to-text-register-callback-returns-only-400s/38174209#38174209)

This user was having the same issues as you with the Speech to Text service. It was an error with the Bluemix servers not supporting the cipher suites for the SSL connection.

It is likely the same issue with the Speech Recognition service.
Please open up a support ticket with your service instance directly here, and they should be able to resolve the issue:

https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/

Comment: You can also open a support ticket from within the Bluemix UI using these steps: https://ibm.biz/support_widget_instructions